# Camel: translate Exception to a different class

Tags: apache-camel

In Camel, if any exception is thrown in my route, I would like to translate it to, say, a domain exception and pass it to the `mock:errors` endpoint for tests. But I can't seem to be able to do it.

```
    errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("mock:errors").maximumRedeliveries(0));

    // even tried this alternative while debugging the processor below
    // to be sure it is not rethrown
      onException(Exception.class).process((Exchange e) -> {
          System.out.println(e.getException()); // breakpoint here
      });

    from("direct:createRequest")
            .onException(Exception.class)
                .handled(true)
                .process(toInvalidRequestException)
            .end()
            .unmarshal().json(Jackson, Request.class)
            .bean(validateRequest);

-------------

private static Processor toInvalidRequestException = exchange -> {
    Exception e = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
    throw new InvalidRequestException(format("Barcode request is not valid or has wrong format: %s",
            getRootCauseMessage(e)), e);
};
```

In the above route, any exception (e.g. validation exception, or Jackson's parsing exception) can be thrown at some point. I intercept it using onException clause and want to translate it to an InvalidRequestException with message detail. This works, but then I want to assert that this exception is actually thrown in my test using the `mock:errors` endpoint. That endpoint is however always empty as the exception is not propagated from the transforming processor.

I tried combinations with `handled(true)` and `continued(true)`, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Error handlers define the default behavior; each error handler will have a list of exception policy definitions (created through the `onException` DSL) which it will first try to match. Only if no match is found will the defaults from `errorHandler` be applied. Also, since you're throwing the exception from the `onException` pipeline, you're basically failing the whole error processing flow.

A better option than wrapping and re-throwing the exception would be to have global `onException` in your route builder that would transform the exception into a **message** of appropriate type and then do the error processing based on the message type / content instead of exception type.

For instance, here's an example of a useful error message that I'm using on my current project:

```
public class DeadLetterChannelMessage {
  private String timestamp = Times.nowInUtc().toString();
  private String exchangeId;
  private String originalMessageBody;
  private Map<String, Object> headers;
  private String fromRouteId;
  private String errorMessage;
  private String stackTrace;

  @RequiredByThirdPartyFramework("jackson")
  private DeadLetterChannelMessage() {
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("ThrowableResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
  public DeadLetterChannelMessage(Exchange e) {
    exchangeId = e.getExchangeId();
    originalMessageBody = e.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    headers = Collections.unmodifiableMap(e.getIn().getHeaders());
    fromRouteId = e.getFromRouteId();

    Optional.ofNullable(e.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class)).ifPresent(throwable -> {
      errorMessage = throwable.getMessage();
      stackTrace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(throwable);
    });
  }

  // getters
}
```

As to why the `exchange.getException()` is empty - you should be using [`Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT`](https://camel.apache.org/why-is-the-exception-null-when-i-use-onexception.html) property to fetch the thrown exception if you're marking the exception as handled:

```
private static Processor toInvalidRequestException = exchange -> {
    Exception e = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
    throw new InvalidRequestException(
            format("Barcode request is not valid or has wrong format: %s",
                    getRootCauseMessage(e)), e);
};
```

Comment: But my code works the same, the exception is there, but the new exception is not rethrown from this subroute to the errorHandler and to the `mock:errors` endpoint.

Comment: Even if I do it this way with handled(true), the `mock:errors` is empty. I will update the question.

Comment: That's because your `onException` overrides the `errorHandler` definition

Comment: But I am throwing from inside the onException, shouldn't it be like throwing from `catch` block in normal java?

Comment: So should I use doTry / doCatch instead?

Comment: Not exactly. Error handlers define the default behavior; each error handler will have a list of onException definitions which it will first try to match. Only if no match is found will the default from `errorHandler` be applied. Also, since you're throwing the exception from the `onException`, you're basically failing the whole error processing flow.

Comment: What I don't understand is why can't you have a global onException definition, why complicate things?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122318/discussion-between-redhead-and-milos-milivojevic).